# Java - Get user input and transferring to main function with Switch case

Tags: java, loops, while-loop, switch-statement

I have a static function which gets and returns a char input.
It will then check the input using a while loop. 
After my main method gets the input, the result will display accordingly to the user input.

Below is my method:

```
public class test
{

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        char choice = getInput(sc);
        String result;
        switch (choice) 
        {
            case ('a'): result = "u choose A";
            break;
        }
    }

    private static char getInput(Scanner keyboard) 
    {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("a, b, c, d, e, q: ");
        char choice = sc.nextLine().trim().toLowerCase().charAt(0); 

        while (choice != 'a' || choice != 'b' || choice != 'c' || choice != 'd' || choice != 'e' || choice != 'q')
        {
            System.out.println("You have entered an invalid entry.");
            System.out.println("a, b, c, d, e, q: ");
            choice = sc.nextLine().trim().toLowerCase().charAt(0);
        }
        return choice;
    }
}
```

However, I am getting the result of invalid input even though I entered the character 'a'.

May I know which part have I gone wrong?

Comment: As an improvement, you could use the 'keyboard' instead of creating a new Scanner object inside the getInput method.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This condition:

```
while (choice != 'a' || choice != 'b' || choice != 'c' || choice != 'd' || choice != 'e' || choice != 'q')
```

will always return true if your choice is not a *or* is not b *or* is not c, etc. Change those `||` operators to `&&` operators and you should be good to go.

Comment: Thank you Ben. I implement your method and it worked. However, I am not able to return the value back to the main, casing my program to end after entering a valid input. May I know how can I change my program? Thank you :)

Comment: It looks like you never print anything to the console in `main`. You probably want to add, for example, `System.out.println(result);` after your `switch` statement.

Comment: Yes, i missed that out and I assumed I can put the printout inside case. Thank you so much

Comment: You actually _can_ print after a `case` label if you want to; the code you posted doesn't call an output method anywhere. But in this case (no pun intended), the clearest thing to do would probably be to use a single print method call after the `switch` statement.